# UITableView Passing Data

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, uitableview

Sorry this is probably a newbie question to alot of you but I've been going round in circles for the last few hours.

I have a table and when the row is pressed pops to second view.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BlogDetailViewController *blogDetailViewController = [[BlogDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlogDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    blogDetailViewController.title = [idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    blogDetailViewController.newsArticle = [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:blogDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Then on my next view I have a text box which i want to display the contents of [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];.

So far i have added this into the secoundview.h

```
@interface BlogDetailViewController : UIViewController{

    NSDictionary *newArticle;
    IBOutlet UITextView *descTextView;

  }


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *newsArticle;
```

I have also @synthesize newsArticle; on the secoundview.m, and linked up the IBOutlet.

So far i have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    descTextView.text = [content];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Hope that explains things I can upload the zip if this does not make sense.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? You didn't ask a question :)

Comment: where is title? how newsArticle go to UITextField?

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear, I want the textview to display the information I have passed to it.

Comment: How can u display a NSDictionary in UITextField? you can display NSString only.

Comment: So if i change it to NSstring, how do i get the string to display inside the descTextView.text

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit puzzled with the question as it's not super clear, but I think what you're doing is passing data from the table view to another view, but the next view isn't displaying the data? The simplest thing to do in that case is add into `viewWillAppear` code that puts the content (`newArticle`?) into the `descTextView`.

Comment: Yeah this is what i want to do, how do i do that?

Comment: In your view controller (`BlogDetailViewControler`) `.m` file you'll have a default method called `viewWillAppear` which triggers before the view is displayed. You'd then extract your content from the NSDictionary (I'm unsure of why you're using a dictionary, or what's in it) and use something like `[self.descTextView setText:(whatever-your-content-is)]`

Comment: sorry this does not work as I want to get the content from blogDetailViewController.newsArticle = [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Well, that's how you set the text in a text view. You've set the newsArticle in `view 1`, in `view 2` you need to set the text view's contents `[textView setText:sometext]`. As you've got your content in an NSDictionary you need to first get it out of the NSDictionary before you set it.

Comment: If I upload my project could you take a look, it will make much more sense.

Answer (score -1):

descTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:newsArticle]; this displayed the string inside the textview